# Sort data using Python based on txt file

Tags: python, linux

I own a txt file that contains many lines
Each line will be as the next

```
username1:password1
username2:password2
...
...
...
usernamexx:passwordxx
```

I want a python code that reads the file line at a time
Where the next is printed

```
user=username1
pass=password1

user=username2
pass=password2

user=username3
pass=password3
...
...
...
user=usernamexx
pass=passwordxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("xxx.txt") as f:
for line  in f.readlines():
   #print(line)
   values = line.split(":")
   user = values[0]
   pasw = values[1]
   print(f"user={user}\npass={pasw}\n")
f.close() #Close the file when you're done.
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open("xxx.txt", "r", encoding="u8") as fp:
    for line_data in fp:
        user, pwd = fp.strip().split(":")
        print(f"user={user}\npass={pwd}\n")
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.